# Enumerate all words of a language in a sequence

Tags: java, enumeration

I've successfully enumerated all words for the languages Σ={a*} and Σ={a^n b^n} with following approach:

```
public class AStar {
    public static int n = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println(next());
        }
    }

    public static String next(){
        String as="" , bs="";
        String s= "";
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            as+="a"; bs+="b";
            s=as+bs;
        }
        n++;
        return s;
    }
}
```

On each call to next(), it prints a word like this(using for loop to invoke next multiple times):
ab, aabb, aaabbb, ......, a^n b^n

**Current Problem**

Now I'm working on a similar class that could enumerate words of language Σ*={a,b}

On each call to next(), it should return a new word that comes after the previously returned word, for instance, it should return these words:

'', 'a', 'b', 'aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb', 'aaa', ...... upto words having n-literals

The ordering of literals does not matter, I've tried this logic but no success so far

```
public class ABStar {
    static int col=0, row=0, cur=0, rlen=0, flag=1, set=0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            System.out.println(next());
        }
    }
    public static String next(){
        String s="";
        row = 1 << col;
        rlen = row/2;
        for(int i=1; i<=row; i++){
            for(int j=1 ; j<=col ; j++){
                if(col==1 && flag ==1){
                    return s+="a";
                }
                else if(col==1 && flag ==2){
                    return s+="b";
                }
                rlen --;
                if(rlen==0){
                    flag = 3-flag;
                    rlen=row/2;
                }
            }
        }
        col++;
        return "";
    }
}
```

I'm using flags col(columns), row(rows), cur(current), flag(1 for a's, 2 for b's), rlen (length of rows for each flag), I'm using these attributes to preserve the states between different calls.

I've tried to solve this problem with almost 2 dozen logics but all in vain, please help me solve this problem, I'll be highly obligated.

Comment: Advice: don't use `+` to concatenate arbitrarily long strings, it allocates a new array every time and makes a full copy, so that's extremely slow. You should use `StringBuilder` for doing such things.

Comment: If order does not matter, then the `a*` generator covers `a^n b^n` too: you're just looking at the first infinity combinations involving only `a` :)

Comment: Have you considered using recursion?

Comment: Instead of using flags, use an integer. If you count from zero to `pow(2, n) - 1`, the bits will go through all the combinations you want: 0 for a, 1 for b. You'd need two loops: one over n, the other over the bits.

Comment: I have to ask, OP, are you a Python guy originally? It looks like you're trying to write a generator with a yield statement, but in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Elegant solution for a two characters alphabet

Since you only have two letters in your alphabet, an elegant solution could be to use binary decomposition of integers (`a` represents a binary `0` and `b` represents a `1`). Here's the algorithm you could implement:

```
private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 3;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int wordLength = 1;
    int current = 0;
    int max = (1 << wordLength) - 1;

    while (wordLength <= MAX_LENGTH) {
        System.out.println(makeWord(current, wordLength));

        if (current < max) current++;
        else {
            wordLength++;
            current = 0;
            max = (1 << wordLength) - 1;
        }
    }
}

private static String makeWord(int current, int wordLength) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
        sb.append((char) ((current % 2) + 'a'));
        current >>= 1;
    }
    return sb.reverse().toString();
}
```

Output:

```
a
b
aa
ab
ba
bb
aaa
aab
aba
abb
baa
bab
bba
bbb
```

### General solution for any alphabet

You can generalize the above solution by counting in base `k` (where `k` is the size of the alphabet) instead of 2. It could look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    listWords(new char[]{ 'e', 'z', 'f' }, 3);
}

private static void listWords(char[] alphabet, int maxWordLength) {
    Arrays.sort(alphabet);
    int base = alphabet.length;

    int wordLength = 1;
    int current = 0;
    int max = (int) Math.pow(base, wordLength) - 1;

    while (wordLength <= maxWordLength) {
        System.out.println(makeWord(alphabet, current, wordLength));

        if (current < max) current++;
        else {
            wordLength++;
            current = 0;
            max = (int) Math.pow(base, wordLength) - 1;
        }
    }
}

private static String makeWord(char[] alphabet, int current, int wordLength) {
    int base = alphabet.length;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
        sb.append(alphabet[current % base]);
        current /= base;
    }
    return sb.reverse().toString();
}
```

Output:

```
e
f
z
ee
ef
ez
fe
ff
fz
ze
zf
zz
eee
eef
eez
efe
eff
efz
eze
ezf
ezz
fee
fef
fez
ffe
fff
ffz
fze
fzf
fzz
zee
zef
zez
zfe
zff
zfz
zze
zzf
zzz
```

Note that this implementation will be much slower than the previous one because divisions and `Math.pow` are slow operations compared to binary shifts.

### Non-arithmetic general solution

The logic of counting in base `k` can also be implemented manually. It might be more efficient but will definitely take more time and code. Below is the general idea of the algorithm:

- you start by filling the string with the lowest value
- then, you increment the value of the last character
- when you can't increment anymore, you reset all the characters at the right of your current position
- you increment your position, and increment the value of this position
- you start all over again doing the same thing from the right of the string

What's cool about this is that if you use a `StringBuilder`, you can minimize the number of array allocation to only one per iteration since each state of the `StringBuilder` can be reached in a few operations (proportional the the length of the string) from the previous state.

Comment: The general solution you describe is counting in base k, where k is the number of characters you have. Since counting in and of itself is base independent, you just need to compute the upper bound for each number of digits, k^n - 1. So if you had the letters a thru j, you'd just count 0-9, 00-99, etc. In this case the decimal digit at each position would correspond directly to the letter and make book keeping very easy.

Comment: Yeah ok, you're saying I could essentially represent the integers between `0` and `k^n - 1`  in base `k` instead of `2`. That's correct, it can be done. I'll provide a general solution applicable to any set of characters. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Yeah. Using numbers and modulo operations is a lot easier than rolling over arrays by hand. Easier to read and to write.

Comment: @MadPhysicist wonder what would be faster though. I would think the cost of divisions could be a problem, but I don't feel brave enough to implement my suggestion to compare both solutions right now

Comment: If I had to guess, it probably doesn't make a huge difference. Switching to C would probably give you waaay more boost than a detail like this.

Comment: @MadPhysicist possibly ^^ There are also two array allocations per iteration in my implementation instead of a single one with a manual counting. It's not worth talking about it if I'm not going to write the other implementation to compare ^^ Have a nice evening (depending on your time zone)

Comment: Evening it is. I'll write something up. Thanks for providing the motivation.

Answer (score 0):

By following @Dici's approach, I've written this code that specifically solves my problem.

```
public class SigmaStar {

//max length of word, just to limit the execution
//change it with your own value
private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 4;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int wordLength = 0;
    int current = 0;
    int max = (1 << wordLength) - 1;

    while (wordLength <= MAX_LENGTH) {
        System.out.println("'"+makeWord(current, wordLength)+"'");

        if (current < max) current++;
        else {
            wordLength++;
            current = 0;
            max = (1 << wordLength) - 1;
        }
    }
}

private static String makeWord(int current, int wordLength) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
        sb.append((char) ((current % 2) + 'a'));
        current >>= 1;
    }
    return sb.reverse().toString();
}

}
```